# How do I specify the path from which my Sublime Text Build will run?

Tags: testing, tdd, mocha.js, sublimetext3

I am trying to run mocha tests from my Sublime Text 3 build module. My mocha build is:

```
/* Mocha.sublime-build */
{
 "shell_cmd": "mocha -c --opts test/mocha.opts $file",
 "shell": true,
 "working_dir": "${project_path}",
 "target": "ansi_color_build",
 "syntax": "Packages/ANSIescape/ANSI.tmLanguage"
}
```

When I use Cmd+B to run my mocha build it responds with an error because my Node version doesn't support "import" statements. I have a mocha.opts file:

```
--require babel-register
--recursive
```

When running Mocha from the command line in the root project directory it works fine. How do I get the Mocha Build system to run from the root directory and receive instructions from mocha.opts?

This is the error that gets reported. It doesnt appear to be running babel.

```
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { expect } from 'chai'
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:220:27
```

Here is what is in my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["stage-0", "es2015"]
}
```

My file structure is:

```
/Project
 ->public
 ->tests
   ->mocha.opts
   ->fooTests
     ->individualFooTest.js
```

Comment: The build runs from the working directory (which above is your project path). However, If there is more than one node, it might be picking up the wrong one. Under MacOS GUI applications like Sublime get a different path than the terminal does, so it might not be finding the version of node you expect. You can get around this by installing https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Fix%20Mac%20Path

Comment: That didn't fix it. The node version shouldn't be causing the issue. Node itself doesn't have support for "import" statements yet so it has to be transpiled using babel. My problem is that the build system is not looking at the mocha.opts file for the instructions that say to use babel. I added some more context above

Comment: Ahh I get you. The `working_dir` is set to `$project_path` in your build system, which expands to the location that your `.sublime-project` is stored in. Is that directory where the `tests/` subdirectory is stored? (some people like to keep their project file separate from the actual folder tree).

Comment: I added my file structure to the question.

Comment: Is `MyProjectFilename.sublime-project` stored at `/Project`?